# Eclipselink JPA ManyToOne mapping issue

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Am new to JPA(eclipselink), am trying to use `ManyToOne unidirectional mapping`, i have `superclass Student` and `subclass Book`, when i try to save the object i end up with exceptions, the details are given below

Student is the Parent Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT")
@TableGenerator(name="student_s", initialValue=1)
public class Student {
    @Id 
    @Column(name="student_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE ,generator="student_s")
    private int studentID;

    @Column(name="full_name",nullable=false)
    private String student_name;

    public int getStudentID() {
        return studentID;
    }

    public void setStudentID(int studentID) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }

    public String getStudent_name() {
        return student_name;
    }

    public void setStudent_name(String student_name) {
        this.student_name = student_name;
    }

}
```

Book is the Child Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BOOK")
@TableGenerator(name="book_s", initialValue=1)
public class Book {
    @Id 
    @Column(name="book_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE ,generator="book_s")
    private int bookID;

    @Column(name="book_name")
    private String bookName;

    @Column(name="student_id")
    private String studentID;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="student_id",referencedColumnName="student_id",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private Student student;

    public int getBookID() {
        return bookID;
    }

    public void setBookID(int bookID) {
        this.bookID = bookID;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }

    public String getStudentID() {
        return studentID;
    }

    public void setStudentID(String studentID) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }


}
```

Main Class which executes the persist operation, while performing persist the unknown column exception is thrown.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){     
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setStudent_name("Prem");

        Book book = new Book();
        book.setBookName("The Best Laid Plan");
        book.setStudent(student);

        EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("premjpaeclipselink");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(book);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
]: sql: Connection(635083092)--INSERT INTO BOOK (book_id, book_name, student_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [351, The Best Laid Plan, null]
[EL Fine]: sql: SELECT 1
[EL Warning]: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'book_name' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: INSERT INTO BOOK (book_id, book_name, student_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [351, The Best Laid Plan, null]
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'book_name' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: INSERT INTO BOOK (book_id, book_name, student_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [351, The Best Laid Plan, null]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:157)
    at org.prem.jpa.eclipselink.Main.main(Main.java:31)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'book_name' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: INSERT INTO BOOK (book_id, book_name, student_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [351, The Best Laid Plan, null]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:962)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:631)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.ParameterizedSQLBatchWritingMechanism.executeBatch(ParameterizedSQLBatchWritingMechanism.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.ParameterizedSQLBatchWritingMechanism.executeBatchedStatements(ParameterizedSQLBatchWritingMechanism.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.writesCompleted(DatabaseAccessor.java:1836)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writesCompleted(AbstractSession.java:4244)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.writesCompleted(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5594)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.acquireWriteLocks(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1646)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitTransactionAfterWriteChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1614)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1169)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:132)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'book_name' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:890)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see this line from your exception stacktrace:

**`Unknown column 'book_name' in 'field list`'**

make sure column "book_name" in BOOK table is correct in database

i hope it helps !!!

Comment: Yes its the problem with the column name, exception is gone but student id is not persisted in the book table, student_id value is 0, the value is not pulled from the parent table Student.

Comment: you don't need student id in BOOK table as you already have student object in BOOK class referenced to Student Entity. Use JPA reverse enginneing tool(to generate Entity classes for you) to avoid this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change `private String studentID;` in Book class to `private int studentID;` and also change respective getter and setter.

Comment: Check in database the book_name field exists with the same name or not. And it is advised that you don't have already existed tales in database and let JPA create tables by its own.

Comment: The column name was wrong in the database, i modified it.

Answer (score 0):

Entity works well. It is the problem of column name. To make sure your DDL, you can use with

`<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>`.

As @Sanket Pipariya said, you don't need

```
@Column(name="student_id")
private String studentID;
```

Because you already have Student Object ('student_id' column in Book table).
You are using `insertable=false` in Student attribute in Book Class so that when you persist Book object along with Student attribute, `student_id` column in Book table will be null.

Answer (score 0):

This exception will be removed when you create table in database of both book and student.
Then the records will be inserted.